# Social icon not visible on site

Tags: html, css, social-networking

I am trying to replicate https://codepen.io/gianmichelle/pen/xpwEh/ on my site . All the effects are working but there is no icon. Instead of icon there is red circle only.

Here is the *Test.html*

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 

  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="social">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="https://twitter.com/gian_michelle">Twitter <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://facebook.com/">Facebook <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="http://dribbble.com/gian_michelle">Dribbble <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="http://behance.net/gianm">Behance <i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the *stylesheet.css* as in the link unfortunately i am unable to find where is the icon defined in the stylesheet or in html

```
a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .me {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 90px auto;
  }
  .me p,
  .me h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .me p {
    font-weight: 200;
  }
  .me span {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .social {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
  }
  .social ul {
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
    transform: translate(-270px, 0);
  }
  .social ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
    width: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
    border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
  }
  .social ul li:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(110px, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(110px, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(110px, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(110px, 0);
    transform: translate(110px, 0);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  }
  .social ul li:hover a {
    color: #000;
  }
  .social ul li:hover i {
    color: #fff;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
  }
  .social ul li i {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  body {
    background: #25343F;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  }
```

Comment: it's working on my machine (local)

Comment: the icon is coming from [font awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) , in this code: 
`<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your solution. Try with this code. Hope it can help.

```css
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.me {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 90px auto;
}

.me p,
.me h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

.me p {
  font-weight: 200;
}

.me span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.social {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
}

.social ul {
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
  transform: translate(-270px, 0);
}

.social ul li {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  width: 300px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
  border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.social ul li:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(110px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(110px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(110px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(110px, 0);
  transform: translate(110px, 0);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.social ul li:hover a {
  color: #000;
}

.social ul li:hover i {
  color: #fff;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.social ul li i {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

body {
  background: #25343F;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="social">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/gian_michelle">Twitter <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://facebook.com/">Facebook <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://dribbble.com/gian_michelle">Dribbble <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://behance.net/gianm">Behance <i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the font awesome link you have given is current or not.

working solution;

```css
a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .me {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 90px auto;
  }
  .me p,
  .me h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .me p {
    font-weight: 200;
  }
  .me span {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .social {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
  }
  .social ul {
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
    transform: translate(-270px, 0);
  }
  .social ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
    width: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
    border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
  }
  .social ul li:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(110px, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(110px, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(110px, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(110px, 0);
    transform: translate(110px, 0);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  }
  .social ul li:hover a {
    color: #000;
  }
  .social ul li:hover i {
    color: #fff;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
  }
  .social ul li i {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  body {
    background: #25343F;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 

  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="social">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="https://twitter.com/gian_michelle">Twitter <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://facebook.com/">Facebook <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="http://dribbble.com/gian_michelle">Dribbble <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="http://behance.net/gianm">Behance <i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>

    </body>
</html>
```